# Mysql Group by time having multiple condition

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Given the sample data below, how can I fetch only one row for each minute of `time`?

I then need to make a condition like this:

```
SELECT IF (`Flag` IS NOT NULL,
           [fetch flag row],
           [otherwise fetch one row from that minute]);
```

Sample data

```
ID  Rate    Flag        time 
1   68.65    null       2012-04-18 10.00.01
2   68.63    null       2012-04-18 10.00.11
3   68.68    null       2012-04-18 10.00.21
4   68.70    null       2012-04-18 10.00.31
5   68.71    null       2012-04-18 10.00.41
6   68.60    null       2012-04-18 10.00.51
7   68.64    null       2012-04-18 10.01.01
8   68.75    null       2012-04-18 10.01.11
9   68.72    1          2012-04-18 10.01.21
10  68.63    null       2012-04-18 10.01.31
11  68.62    null       2012-04-18 10.01.41
12  68.60    null       2012-04-18 10.01.51

Expected Output
1   68.65    null       2012-04-18 10.00.01
9   68.72    1          2012-04-18 10.01.21
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT FLAG as signal, DATE_FORMAT(TIME, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as time, RATE as rate
       FROM RATES WHERE (FLAG!='' || (DATE_FORMAT(TIME, '%s')>50 ))
   GROUP BY time
   ORDER BY time DESC,FLAG DESC;
```

Comment: SELECT FLAG as signal , DATE_FORMAT(TIME, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as time,  RATE as rate  FROM  RATES  WHERE  (FLAG!='' || (DATE_FORMAT(TIME, '%s')>50  ))  GROUP BY time   ORDER BY time DESC,FLAG DESC

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be described as: find a row with maximum flag in every set of rows grouped by the same minute, choose any if more than one row has the same flag.
So the query should look like:

```
SELECT r.id, r.rate, rg.flag, rg.minute
FROM
  ( SELECT MAX(flag) as flag , DATE_FORMAT(`TIME`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as minute
     FROM RATES
     GROUP BY minute ) rg
JOIN RATES r
ON r.id =(SELECT ru.id FROM RATES ru
          WHERE ru.flag <=> rg.flag
          AND ru.time BETWEEN CONCAT(rg.minute,':00') AND CONCAT(rg.minute,':59')
          LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: This is fine, but I have huge records in my table, this query will takes long execution.

Comment: It sure will be slow on a big table because of grouping on some derived value instead of column from table, making it impossible to use index for grouping. You could try adding a datetime column with times approximated to full minutes and use it for grouping and join, it will be a lot faster with index. But on a really huge table it would be best to flag single rows for every minute. How exactly do you flag them right now? Do you add flags manually?

Comment: Table is updating rows in every 5 sec, and we are not setting flag manually ,the flag is not frequent one it may happend one or two times in an hour.